# Angular 5/6 project session storage

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular5, ngrx, session-storage

recently I am thinking of how to main a session object like using session in traditional asp.net project, since this would be some information
that'll constantly using through the web application like userId/appId/userRole and we don't want to retrieve the information from database every time when use these as input, so far what I found out the possible solutions would be:

1) Put them into html5 local/session storage, however I am not sure if
    that's safe to the public
    user? Suppose I save userId as 1 in session storage, **would user go and modify this value to 2 on his local browser storage, so after that when saving something and need to grab the userId from session storage, it would grab userId 1 or 2? Or would user go and delete the key/pair in session storage which would cause an error in the application when trying to look for it**

2) Save them into a angular service class as an object and use it like a global object, would this be a good idea?

Which of the above solution would be best to solve my issue in Angular project? Or does anyone have a smarter idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a library to do exactly this.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache

RxCache is a library that simplifies the push model of Redux style stores and also supports local storage to survive browser refresh.

Comment: That is awesome and exact what I am looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1) You can store in th html storage to make it unreadable you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lz-string . This will also compress all data and will not let the localStorage or sessionsStorage hit their quota.

2 and 3) These both are tools that make use of the html localStorage/sessionStorage. I just use the html5 with an lz-string compress decompress.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your idea! The concern that using localStorage/sessionStorage is that client user may get the stored information from the browser, and I am not sure if that's a secure design to expose information like userId, userRole to client, and maybe these information could be modified or hacked for security reason.

Comment: So where exactly is the data stored via ng-lz-string? Doe it have an expiration? how would I do if I want to store the user object data by using  ng-lz-string after logging then pick it up any time within any service or components?

Comment: That's a total different question and up to yourself.
This will just compress and decompress data.
How you do that is up to you.

Comment: I see, so the "ng-lz-string" is not for compress AND store data, it only does the compress and later on we still need to save it somewhere like html storage, correct?

Comment: Yes indeed sir.